# Windows 7 HP Color Laserjet 1600 on home network doesn't print

Tags: windows, printer, network-printer, homegroup

I've got Windows 7 and shared printers in my homegroup which I can see in Windows Explorer.
I've also installed the latest HP drivers.  But whenever I try to print to the networked Laserjet on the remote computer, the document just hangs in the printer queue.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you print a test page from either machine?

Comment: I can spool a test page from my machine but it doesn't print.  I can spool and print from the remote machine that hosts the printer, which is visible in my homegroup and in my printer list in the Print Dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft forum sent me the answer; that's another two hours from my life that I can't get back. Thanks, HP!

From http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/3c2466d3-d137-40dd-823d-23cd:

> If this is the Zenographics driver
>   that HP has written for many of these
>   class of devices (filenames are
>   Z.....), you will need to uncheck
>   Enable Bidirectional on the ports tab
>   to disable the Zenographics language
>   monitor.  It requires access to one of
>   it required files that the remote user
>   does not have access to.

Answer (score 1):

According to HP phone support, HP does not provide a driver for this printer which is compatible with Win 7 64-bit and will not be doing so.  I was told that my only options are to change printer or change computer.  The driver which is identified on the HP site, by the way, is the Vista driver and will not proceed with the wizard beyond the EULA.